# Look up Envelope by DocumentId?

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I'm just getting started with the DocuSign REST API (creating a proof-of-concept integration with my company's product) and am trying to wrap my head around everything. There are a couple things I can't find much info on:

1. When creating an Envelope, does the `documentId` matter? I assume if there are multiple documents the `documentId` for each would need to be different. Is it used anywhere else?
2. Periodically, I'd like to check the Audit Events for an Envelope. It would be much easier if I could look up the Envelope (or go straight to the Audit Events without looking up the Envelope) with a `documentId` instead. Is this possible?

Our product already stores documents, and therefore has a `documentId` - so that is the ID I am using when creating Envelopes. What I'd like to do is, with whatever document I am viewing in our product is check to see if there are any non-completed Envelopes pending. Then I wouldn't need to store any DocuSign related data in our system (i.e. `envelopeId`).

**Can I look up an Envelope by the `documentId` used to create it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `documentId` is a client defined property and is simply there to help you tag the documents that were used for given envelopes.  If you want to track the documents that you're supplying in your envelopes (which it sounds like you are) then you can use it to uniquely identify the underlying docs and if you already have a system that has generated the documentIds then that should make things easier.
2. No there is not a way to retrieve envelope information through `documentId`.  The best solution is most likely to store a simple table on your side that links `documentIds` to `envelopeIds`, then given the `documentId` you want to search for use the linked envelopeId to retrieve its status.

You should note, though, that there are certain API call limits in place for some API calls and requesting envelope status is one of them.  You are not allowed to request status on a given envelope more than 1 once every 15 mins.  Instead, the [DocuSign Connect](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/connect) module is recommended if you want to track real-time status (DocuSign Connect pushes status out to you as soon as it happens instead of you polling for status every so often).

For more info on API call limits check out the API Best Practices doc in the DocuSign Developer Center under the Go Live section:
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/go-live/certification